# Copy a directory between two remote hosts using ansible

Tags: remote-access, ansible

My aim is to copy a latest build(folder) from my remote server A(Ubuntu machine) to a remote server B(Windows server 2012) using my ansible control server C(centos machine).I can ping to both of my remote hosts using the control node. The following are the contents of my playbook :

deploy.yaml

```
---
 - hosts: windows_ip
   tasks:
     - name: Deploy Jenkins build
       synchronize: mode=pull src=src_address dest=destination_address
       delegate_to: jenkins_ip
```

however i get the following error :

fatal: [windows_ip -> jenkins_ip] => Authentication failure.

M i following the right approach? if so what is the issue here

Answer (score 1):

Because `synchronize` module need `rsync` installed both in local and remote machine. So that task was failed.

To copy file to windows box, you can use [win_copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_copy_module.html) module. But it doesn't copy from remote machine to remote machine.